# What is the standard deviation of this random variable? (I want to check my calculation)

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, sequences-and-series, trigonometry

Consider the random variable (orientation angle) $0\le\theta\le 2\pi$ with the following PDF where $\theta_0$ is the mean orientation angle: $(n\in\mathbb Z , n\ge 0)$

$$p(\theta,\theta_0,n)=\frac{\cos^{2n}(\theta-\theta_0)}{\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}(\theta-\theta_0) \, d\theta}$$
What is the variance of the random variable $\theta$ in terms of $n$

I have taken these steps:
First of all we should calculate $A_n=\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^{2n}(\theta-\theta_0)\,d\theta$
From the Integration by substitution method assuming that $x=\theta-\theta_0$ we have:
$$A_n=\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}\cos^{2n}x\,dx$$
From page $30$ in [Elementary Functions](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780122947605500155) we know:
$$\cos^{2n}x=\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\cos 2(n-k)x$$
Then
$$A_n=\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}\,dx+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}\cos 2(n-k)x\,dx$$
About the second integral in the above expression, we know that the period of the function $\cos 2(n-k)x$ is $\frac{\pi}{n-k}$
So the length of the interval $[-\theta_0,-\theta_0+2\pi]$ is $2(n-k)$ times the period which is an integer coefficient of the period, that means the answer of this integral will be $0$
So $$A_n=\frac{\pi}{2^{2n-1}}\binom{2n}{n}$$
The PDF mentioned at the begining will be converted to:
$$p(\theta,\theta_0,n)=\frac{\cos^{2n}(\theta-\theta_0)}{A_n}$$
So the variance will be:
$$\sigma^2(\theta)=\frac{1}{A_n}\int_0^{2\pi}(\theta-\theta_0)^2\cos^{2n}(\theta-\theta_0)\,d\theta$$
Again from the Integration by substitution method and the aforementioned relation we have:
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}(\theta-\theta_0)^2\cos^{2n}(\theta-\theta_0)\,d\theta
&=\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}x^2\cos^{2n}x\,dx\\
&=\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}x^2(\frac{1}{2^{2n}}\binom{2n}{n}+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\cos 2(n-k)x)\,dx\\
&=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}\underbrace{\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}x^2\,dx}_1\\
&+\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\underbrace{\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}x^2\cos 2(n-k)x\,dx}_2
\end{align}$$
About the first integral in the above equation, we have
$$(1):\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}x^2\,dx=\left[\frac{x^3}{3}\right]_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}=\frac{8\pi^3-12\pi^2\theta_0+6\pi\theta_0^2}{3}$$
And about the second integral:
$$(2):\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}x^2\cos 2(n-k)x\,dx$$
From integration by parts method:
$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{Derivation}&\text{Integration}\\
\hline
{} \oplus x^2 & \cos 2(n-k)x  \\
{} \ominus 2x & \frac{1}{2(n-k)}\sin 2(n-k)x \\
{} \oplus 2 & \frac{-1}{2^2(n-k)^2}\cos 2(n-k)x \\
{} \ominus 0 & \frac{-1}{2^3(n-k)^3}\sin 2(n-k)x
\end{array}
$$
$$\begin{align}
(2):\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}x^2\cos 2(n-k)x\,dx &=\left[\frac{x^2}{2(n-k)}\sin 2(n-k)x\right]_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi} \tag 1\\
&+\left[\frac{x}{2(n-k)^2}\cos 2(n-k)x\right]_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi} \tag 2 \\
&-\left[\frac{1}{2^2(n-k)^3}\sin 2(n-k)x\right]_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi} \tag 3
\end{align}$$
For $(1)$ regarding the facts $\sin (2n\pi+\theta)=\sin\theta$ and $\sin(-\theta)=-\sin\theta$ after some simplifications, we have $$(1)=\frac{2\pi(\theta_0-\pi)}{n-k}\sin 2(n-k)\theta_0$$
For $(2)$ regarding the facts $\cos (2n\pi+\theta)=\cos\theta$ and $\cos(-\theta)=\cos\theta$ after some simplifications, we have $$(2)=\frac{\pi}{(n-k)^2}\cos 2(n-k)\theta_0$$
Also after some simplifications, we conclude that $(3)=0$
So:$$\int_{-\theta_0}^{-\theta_0+2\pi}x^2\cos 2(n-k)x\,dx=\frac{2\pi(\theta_0-\pi)}{n-k}\sin 2(n-k)\theta_0+\frac{\pi}{(n-k)^2}\cos 2(n-k)\theta_0$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}(\theta-\theta_0)^2\cos^{2n}(\theta-\theta_0)\,d\theta=\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}\frac{8\pi^3-12 \pi^2 \theta_0 + 6\pi\theta_0^2}{3}+{}\\
&\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\left(\frac{2\pi(\theta_0-\pi)}{n-k}\sin 2(n-k)\theta_0+\frac{\pi}{(n-k)^2}\cos 2(n-k)\theta_0\right)
\end{align}$$
And the variance will be:
$$\frac{2^{2n-1}}{\binom{2n}{n}\pi}\left(\begin{align}
&\frac{\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{2n}}\frac{8\pi^3-12\pi^2\theta_0+6\pi\theta_0^2}{3}+{}\\
&\frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n}{k}\left(\frac{2\pi(\theta_0-\pi)}{n-k}\sin 2(n-k)\theta_0+\frac{\pi}{(n-k)^2}\cos 2(n-k)\theta_0\right)
\end{align}\right)$$
With the final form:
$$\sigma^2(\theta)=\frac{4\pi^2-6\pi\theta_0+3\theta_0^2}{3}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!n!}{k!(2n-k)!}\left(\frac{2(\theta_0-\pi)}{n-k}\sin 2(n-k)\theta_0+\frac{1}{(n-k)^2}\cos 2(n-k)\theta_0\right)$$
So it seems that the variance is dependent to $\theta_0$(mean orientation angle) and even if we assume $\theta_0=0$
$$\sigma(\theta)=\sqrt{\frac{4\pi^2}{3}+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n!n!}{k!(2n-k)!}.\frac{1}{(n-k)^2}}$$
But in the papers that I'm studying:
[A General Characterization for Polarimetric Scattering From Vegetation Canopies](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5467148&refinements%3D4230897956%26filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A5552163%29)
[Adaptive Model-Based Decomposition of Polarimetric SAR Covariance Matrices](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/articleDetails.jsp?arnumber=5659970&refinements%3D4230897956%26filter%3DAND%28p_IS_Number%3A5719225%29)
It has been pointed out that:
[image]
Also the limit of the expression that I get finally is not $0$ an $n\to +\infty$ which is not consistent with our hypothesis
I'm really confused

Comment: do i really have to read all of this to understand your question? or is there some more essential part?

Comment: I edited for proper use of \tag and some minor formatting.  Notice that \oplus x^2 and {}\oplus x^2 yield slightly different results: $$\oplus x^2$$ versus  $${}\oplus x^2$$  There's a reason for that and it's not hard to see what the reason is. $\qquad$

Comment: You might get a better response if you shorten your question.

Comment: Often people here complain that questions are too short. $\qquad$

Comment: @avid19 in fact the main question is to calculate this integral $\sigma^2(\theta)=\frac{1}{A_n}\int_0^{2\pi}(\theta-\theta_0)^2\cos^{2n}(\theta-\theta_0)\,d\theta$, I've done it but I don't know what I have done wrong. Just calculate it and tell me if I have done wrong and ok I will shorten the question

Comment: @MichaelHardy see the above comment

Comment: @MichaelChirico see the above comment

Comment: ok, I will shorten the question now

Comment: I have omitted the unnecessary parts. But if you think that there still are parts that can be omitted please feel free to edit an shorten the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment: without getting into the details of your calculation, I think there is a more fundamental problem here. On one side, you are treating $\theta$ as a scalar variable that takes values in the real interval $[0,2\pi]$, and then you define a pdf over that interval and compute the mean, variance, etc by integrating over that interval. But that conflicts with your interpretation of $\theta$ as an angle. For example, suppose you had a pdf for $\theta$ that is concentrated (evenly) at $[0,\epsilon]$ and $[2\pi - \epsilon, 2\pi]$, for very small $\epsilon$. Seeing $\theta $ as an angle, we'd say that it's variance is very small (and it's mean is zero). Computing it as pdf, we wouldn't get that result.

Also, you assume that $\theta_0$ is the mean of your density, but that, again, is incompatible with you formulation. Think of $\theta_0 =0$...

Further, take for example $n=1$, $\theta_0=1$. The density function (graph) has period $2\pi$ (as it should), and its integral gives $1$ over the interval $[0,2\pi]$ as well as over (say) $[-\pi,3/2\, \pi ]$  (as it should).

[image]

But if we compute the mean and variance by the standard formulas we'd get, integrating over $[0,2\pi]$ : $\mu=2.687$ (already a meaningless result!) and $\sigma^2=2.8750$. If we take $[-\pi,3/2\, \pi ]$ (it should not matter), it gives instead $\mu=2.02545$ and $\sigma^2=2.79192$

All this needs rethinking. That's not the way to deal with circular statistics, I'm afraid. http://www.theanalysisfactor.com/circular-statistics/ 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics

Comment: Ok, I've decided to [start from scratch](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/192537/79636), seems that there's something wrong in the papers and also in my calculations. I've tried to obtain the book [statistical analysis of circular data](https://books.google.com/books?id=wGPj3EoFdJwC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Statistical+Analysis+of+Circular+Data&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCnc_2-cbKAhVB_nIKHe4FChwQ6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=Statistical%20Analysis%20of%20Circular%20Data&f=false) but I haven't been so successfull

Comment: Would you please go and have a look at [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/193283/79636)